# GeoServer with Docker, no manifest found

Tags: geoserver, docker

I haven't managed to get GeoServer working with Tomcat (but am still trying). I decided to give Docker a shot, but when I run `sudo docker pull docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.24-SNAPSHOT` from [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/docker.html), it says manifest not found.

Comment: Try 2.22.2 or 2.23-snapshot which will exist

Comment: I would follow this page (https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/docker.html) - but infact that doesn't work either - `sudo docker pull docker.osgeo.org/geoserver:2.22.2` does work though

Comment: 10ac4908093d and c65e9b395283 are taking an unusually long time to download.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing `2.23-RC1` is the latest tag of the available docker images. See here: https://docker.osgeo.org/#browse/browse:docker:v2%2Fgeoserver%2Ftags%2F2.23-RC1

The versions of the official docker images (https://github.com/geoserver/docker) are a bit delayed to the releases of the core GeoServer software. If you really need to use the latest GeoServer version via Docker. You can build the image by yourself.